# CryptoJS incorrect AES encoding

Tags: javascript, php, aes, cryptojs

Why is the output from CryptoJS different than in PHP' openssl_encrypt if I'm using the same key and ivector?

```
openssl_encrypt('test' , 'aes-256-cbc', '17cc0ffd728f34c171e06c47df4227a32ee6ef5d6c60398eeab30cf34306c644', 0 , base64_decode('aROnq5DocMLgrlpAF6yjgw=='));
```

Output:

```
oIcizpTDCTgtTGu3lO1cJg==
```

Each time the same output.

CryptoJS:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("test", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('UDOuDk5uxceoFWxtrabuEhamMC1T4Abr'), {
iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('HLcM0VZYfsgPo2ye')}).toString();
```

Output:

```
VTJGc2RHVmtYMTlrVHh4N0F3V2VySWlFcjBGeWlRRkcyMmNabEtjWmpmYz0=
```

Why is the output from CryptoJS different each time?

## Edit:

After your hints:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("test", CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('UDOuDk5uxceoFWxtrabuEhamMC1T4Abr'), {
iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('HLcM0VZYfsgPo2ye')}).toString();
```

Output:

```
CoFpbmd4YzOiVEFzVkeaDQ==
```

Now each time is the same

But is different than in PHP:

```
openssl_encrypt("test" , "aes-256-cbc", "UDOuDk5uxceoFWxtrabuEhamMC1T4Abr", 0 , "HLcM0VZYfsgPo2ye");
```

Output:

```
oV9OZVYM80p8mlHH5wnzEg==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CryptoJS.AES.encrypt will try to automatically use AES-128, AES-192 or AES-256 depending on the key you pass it. In your case, you pass a secret passphrase ('17cc0f...') instead of a key  which will cause it to generate its own AES-256 key.

[The documentation states](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/):

> CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the
>   variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase,
>   then it will generate a 256-bit key.

In order to use a key, you must parse a Hex key first and pass that.

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("test", key, { iv: iv });
```